# Replace multiple words with only one word in googlesheets with apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google sheets with texts in 590 rows. I need to replace multiple words of these texts in other word as a category. For example, I need to find the words "brontolaren minacciaren pettegolezzin maleducaton" and replace them with the word "relazionin". I'm trying to write an apps scripts to do this, and I found a script created by [FluffyLlemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39169590/replace-multiple-strings-in-google-spreadsheet-with-script/50322167#50322167:%7E:text=at%201%3A42-,FluffyLlemon,-1351) that I adapted, and I thought could work for me:

```
  function FindAndReplace() {
  var data_range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange();  
  var num_rows = data_range.getNumRows();
  var num_columns = data_range.getNumColumns();
  

  var find_replace ={
     "brontolaren" : "relazionen", 
     "minacciaren" : "relazionen", 
     "pettegolezzin" : "relazionen",
     "maleducaton" : "relazionen", 
     "riservatezzan" : "relazionen", 
     "sottopressionen": "relazionen",
     }

    Object.keys(find_replace).map(function(find) {
    var replace = find_replace[find];
    for (var row=1; row <= num_rows; row++) {
     for (var col=1; col <= num_columns; col++) {
        var value = data_range.getCell(row, col).getValue();
        if (data_range.getCell(row, col).getFormula()) {continue;}
        try {
           value = value.replace(find, replace);
           data_range.getCell(row, col).setValue(value);
        }
        catch (err) {continue;}
     }
  }
 });
}
```

By executing this code, just the first word is replaced and not the others, and it seems to take a long time and never stop. This is the first time I use apps script... How can I improve the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
function FindAndReplace() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var rg = ss.getDataRange();  
  const r = "relazionen";
  const f =["brontolaren","minacciaren","pettegolezzin","maleducaton","riservatezzan","sottopressionen"];
  f.forEach(n => {
    rg.createTextFinder(n).replaceAllWith(r);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As another approach, in this sample script, the value of `search` is used as a regex.

#### Sample script:

```js
function FindAndReplace() {
  const search = ["brontolaren", "minacciaren", "pettegolezzin", "maleducaton", "riservatezzan", "sottopressionen"];
  const replace = "relazionen";
  SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSheet()
    .getDataRange()
    .createTextFinder(search.join("|"))
    .useRegularExpression(true)
    .replaceAllWith(replace);
}
```

#### Note:

- When several values are replaced with one value, the process cost can be reduced by the above method. But, when several values are replaced with each unique value, this report might be useful. [Ref](https://tanaikech.github.io/2022/08/19/benchmark-high-efficiency-finding-and-replacing-many-values-in-google-spreadsheet-with-low-process-cost-using-google-apps-script/)

#### References:

- [createTextFinder(findText)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createtextfinderfindtext)
- [useRegularExpression(useRegEx)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#useRegularExpression(Boolean))
- [replaceAllWith(replaceText)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#replaceallwithreplacetext)

Comment: Thank you! Very useful the references too.